# Date filter for inserting into DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have built a simple crawler for one of our clients. I am facing issues with duplicate entries in the database.

Basically what I am doing is looking into a website which has a lot of houses for sale and then pulling from there the address, postcode, town, price and status.

Later when inserting into database I am also generating `creation_date` .

The reason for that is that the name CAN be duplicate in case it has been INSERTED at least 2 years ago. So one house can be twice in the database, as long as the creation dates are within a minimum of 2 years range.

```
<?php 
    //Comparison to current houses

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT street, postcode, town, price, status, creation_time, print_status FROM house"); // Selecting the table

    if (!$query) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); // checking for errors
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        // $row['street'];
        // $row['postcode'];
        // $row['town'];
        // $row['price'];
        // $row['status'];

        $creation_time = $row['creation_time'];
        $print_status = $row['print_status'];

        $c = 0;
        foreach ($houses as $house) {
            $creation_time_u = strtotime($creation_time); // Makes creation time into Unix
            $life_time = strtotime('+2 years', $creation_time_u); // Calculates +2 years from creation time
            if (($row['street'] == $house[0]) && ($row['postcode'] == $house[1]) && ($row['town'] == $house[2]) && ($life_time >= $now)) {
                    unset($houses[$c]); // maybe use implode? When i do unset its leaving the array but the values are gone, so we get an empty row
            }   
        }
        $c++;
        $houses = array_values($houses); // FIXES BROKEN INDEX AFTER USING UNSET
    }
?>
```

After this has been completed, 
I insert the new $houses array into the database and then print, which is the next step but kind of irrelevant in this case.

So, i don't know exactly what is going wrong. If I run it twice in a row, it doesn't enter duplicate entries but if I run it the next day or something.

It makes the same entry but double. Here is an example of what i found in the database:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t8o1.png)

So yeah, I have spent too much time looking at this code and I can't figure out why my filter is not working. I expect it has to do with how I am managing time, but not completely sure.

Please advice!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: before you insert any data either save data in small or upper case. 
trim extra spaces. this will help you check the data . Later you can show what ever way you want.

Comment: Instead of using unset on the row, you could use a new array to store the values that you want to insert. It would be easier for debugging as well because you could then compare the 2 arrays

Comment: @Fred-ii- no errors are yielding from this. I did try however to check the variables that store my time and then I got an error. I added the lines `echo $creation_time_u; echo $life_time;` and then i get an error `Notice: Undefined variable: creation_time_u in /home/whale/domains/whale-agency.com/public_html/svd_qa/crawl.php on line 78` which is weird, considering that those variables are defined in the `foreach` loop for the `$houses` array.

Comment: @mikeyq6 good idea, man. I will try to see if i can figure something out. I am currently thinking that this happens because of the way I am formating the dates and creating the `$life_time` variable. Now testing if it works better with `$date->add(new DateInterval('P2Y'));`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculationg the time-interval in php you should select relevant houses in your SQL-query (see DATE_ADD [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)):

```
 SELECT 
      street, postcode, town, price, status, creation_time, print_status 
 FROM house AS a
 JOIN house AS b
      ON a.street = b.street
      AND a.postcode = b.postcode
      AND a.town = b.town
 WHERE
      a.creation_time <= DATE_ADD(creation_time, INTERVAL 2 YEARS) -- select duplicates
```

Comment: thanks man. I will def implement this approach. I can imagine it will also make the process faster as I don't have to look through the complete database every time.